# How to plot a multiple functions density in one histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram, density-plot

I wish to draw different density functions in the same histogram. This is one example:
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
   geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../40), 
                  fill = "gray70", color = "gray50") +
  geom_density(aes(color = "default")) +
  geom_density(adjust = 2, aes(color = "longer")) +
  geom_density(adjust = 1/2, aes(color = "shorter")) +
  geom_density(kernel = "epanechnikov", aes(color = "epanechnikov")) +
  geom_density(kernel = "rectangular", aes(color = "rectangular")) +
  geom_density(kernel = "cosine", aes(color = "cosine"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And here is a solution with *plot* from R base: Use *plot* (or *hist*) for the first plot and *lines* for subsequent plots.

Beware to use `freq=FALSE`, because otherwise the histogram area is not normalized to one.

```
x <- rnorm(50)
hist(x, freq=F)
xx <- seq(min(x)-0.5, max(x)+0.5, 0.01)
lines(xx, dnorm(xx), col="red")
lines(density(x), col="blue")
```

[image]